# VS2010 Custom Code Analysis Rule

Tags: visual-studio-2010, code-analysis, fxcop

I'm trying to write a custom fxcop rule for mstest projects VS2010.  I'd like to debug it but keep getting an exception when it tries to load the dll for the mstest project it fails stating that it can't find referenced assembly:

```
  
   Microsoft.FxCop.Common.AssemblyLoadException
   Could not load C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\20100106-CodeAnalysisRulesBlogDemo\BlogDemo\TestProject1\bin\Debug\TestProject1.dll.
   Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk.InvalidMetadataException
   The following error was encountered while reading module 'TestProject1': Assembly reference cannot be resolved: Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.
```

Does anyone have any idea how to resolve this?  If I just run the code analysis it works fine but as soon as I try to debug it fails.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the /d option to specify additional directories to search during assembly resolving.

Code Analysis doesn't automatically fetch assemblies from the project settings, unless you've all set them to Copy-local.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the mess of writing FxCop rules would be to use the tool NDepend. This tool that lets write **Code Rules over C# LINQ Queries** [what we call CQLinq](http://www.ndepend.com/Features.aspx#CQL). *Disclaimer: I am one of the developers of the tool*

More than [200 code rules](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html) are proposed by default. Customizing existing rules or creating your own rules is straightforward thanks to the *well-known* C# LINQ syntax.

CQLinq queries can be edited live in VisualStudio, and offer instant result, with result browsing facilities:

[image: CQLinq rules]

Rules can be verified [live in Visual Studio](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_VS_CQL.aspx) and at Build Process time, in a [generated HTML+javascript report](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_CI_Report.aspx#CQLRule).